# Web app to a packaged app with Dart

Tags: dart

I've been struggling with this for a few hours now. I've looked around and I believe I'm doing everything correctly, but it's just not working. Just for fun, I'm taking the [sample Dart stopwatch](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-tutorials-samples/tree/master/web/target06/stopwatch) and making it into a Chrome packaged app. It works flawlessly in both Dartium Chrome(via dart2js) when it's a simple web app, however as a packaged app it works in neither. The dart code simply doesn't work. Are there additional steps I need to perform to make Dart work in a web app?

Thank you very much for any help you can provide!

Comment: I don't know a lot about building packaged apps using Dart, but you should probably provide some more details about what you doing. That way, someone here will be able to pinpoint the problems.

Comment: Also, you are aware of http://blog.dartwatch.com/2012/12/using-dart-for-chrome-packaged-apps.html, right?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few caveats when writing a packaged app in Dart. One is related to symlinks (packaged apps don't like them, and pub uses them), and the other is related to dart2js (you need to compile with the --disallow-unsafe-eval flag).

If you're using the Editor, you can create a new chrome packaged app from the wizard. This will set up a project that handles both issues above. I'd do that and make sure it runs, and then copy your web app into that project.